# browser stuck on ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery

i developed a simple web site which uses ajax to load content and while the content is loading, i'm displaying a progress. Everything works as expected on 1st ajax call but after that, it becomes a mess

1. page gets stuck on ajax call
2. i've written a function to listen to ajax call and show loading message, it doesn't work too and the page becomes very laggy and slow after the 1st ajax call.

Here is my ajax function.

```
function loadPage(path) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context: document.body,
    dataType: "html",
    timeout: 10000,
    url: path
});}
```

i tried to async to true but its true by default. still it didn't help. a demo of the problem can be seen at : REMOVED SINCE PROBLEM SOLVED

This works perfectly fine on the localhost but as soon as i uploaded it to my remote server,problems started to occur. can an expert please be kind point out what have i done wrong ? i tried removing all little the animations from this, non helped.

---

the problem was me loading javascript files on each ajax cal causing too many get and post requests and unnecessary dom changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your page seems to be slow with every click, because you are constantly loading JavaScript files on every click instead of just loaded the JavaScript once when the page loads, since you are grabbing the whole HTML page

like for instance.. every time you click on HOME .. these files are loaded in the page again..

```
POST http://3rsmj.com/new/home.html 

GET http://3rsmj.com/new/js/liquid/jquery.easing.1.3.js?_=1382114556389

GET http://3rsmj.com/new/js/liquid/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js?_=1382114556390

GET http://3rsmj.com/new/js/liquid/jquery.liquid-slider-custom.min.js?_=1382114556391
```

if using AJAX its best to just load the content in or in fragments so not having to load all the scripts on every menu click .. or load the data and populate the data in the content

have you tried looking into the jQuery **load()** method for loading in HTML fragments so to not have to load in the whole HTML DOM again

http://api.jquery.com/load/

like this:

```
 $("#load_area").load("portfolio_item.html #ID_of_content_to_grab");
```

the above would go to **portfolio_item.html** and grab the html fragment from the id **#ID_of_content_to_grab** and insert it into **#load_area**

**UPDATE:**

you can also try to empty the #load_area before you insert new content

```
$("#load_area").html("");
$("#load_area").load("portfolio_item.html #ID_of_content_to_grab");
```

or you can use jquery **[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)** .. or test both out

..

Comment: what are loading in.. do you have all your js loaded in the main page and then loading only fragments into the content? are those changes live on your site now?.. and what is the js file on your site that has those new changes to inspect on your site? when i go to your link above its showing you still load all the html and js in the page each click

Comment: Loaded All the resources on index page. Works fine :-)
Thank you very much :)

Comment: also i noticed if you want to keep the scroll bar from disappearing and reappearing every time you click the menu, you can add a **min-height** to the #load_area div.. like maybe **min-height: 500px;** so this way the scroll bar will stay visible and not push your body left and right when clicking the top menu

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39530/discussion-between-jonathan-and-driverboy)